# How to count DataItem in c# using stored procedure with repeater control?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I want to know how to count items/products using stored procedure in Asp.net C#.

**Example** :

****Categories****

Shoes : 2 items

Paint : 7 items

Skirts : 204 items

Abaya : 1 items

Burka : 6 items

I have Written stored procedure "**GetItemCount**" but how to call it in c# code i do not know plz help me.

it is working fine Query showing result as per my desire.

```
SELECT id, category, ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM entry_table WHERE 
category.id = entry_table.cat_id) as cnt FROM category
```

plz check screen-shot below. 
http://www.fzkdesign.com/img/item-count.jpg

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.cnt")%>
```

Regards

firoz khan

Answer (score 0):

use this to run Stored Procedure from c#

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(stringConection))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetItemCount", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;             
                conn.Open();
                DataSet ds= new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you need to check this http://stackoverflow.com/about on how to accept answers that worked. if you don't accept your answers, then in future people will not prefer to help out you in problems. Thx